# 404: PecanNotFound OpenStack Neutron

Tags: openstack-neutron

I am seeing this error during a neutron server restart, I am not using pecan at all, so I would like to get rid of this warning, any idea how to solve it? I am running queens release

```
timestamp id WARNING neutron.pecan_wsgi.controllers.root [req-something account - - default -] No controller found for: floatingips - returning response code 404: PecanNotFound
```

Comment: Hey Iago, Did you found any fix ?